# JavaScript - Center HTML List on Centre

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a drop down list as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx99T.png

I want that whenever an option is selected. It is centered in the list i.e. it is automatically centered like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGygZ.png

Whenever the user selects an option the grey box goes to the bottom. I already have a javascript which automatically submits the selection to a database which I which to keep.

I am still novice with javascript.

This is part of my code:

```
echo '<form id="PrimaryCatForm" action="" method="post">';
echo '<select name="primary_cat" size="9" style="width: 400px;"
onChange="document.getElementById(\'PrimaryCatForm\').submit();"> ';
```

This is what I want to achieve

1. keep the `onChange="document.getElementById(\'PrimaryCatForm\').submit()`;
2. The select has size 9 - I want that whenever an option is selected it is centered
3. I want the selection to remain active i.e. remain blue and not turn into grey due to the `onChange="document.getElementById(\'PrimaryCatForm\').submit()`

I think I may have found a [solutuion here](http://jsfiddle.net/BA39h/1/)but I am not sure how to integrate it in my problem

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @Quantastical I started learning programming recently. I don't know any javascript. Sorry.

Comment: its not possible unless you use a custom created select element. select elements are handled natively by the respective browser. It would be very easy to create a custom select element using a readonly text field with an css triangle arrow in the before pseudo-selector, that triggers a ul with a fixed height and overflow-y:scroll.

Comment: @Quantastical - I think I may have found a solution but I am not sure how to integrate it in my solution - http://jsfiddle.net/BA39h/1/

Comment: JavaScript works client-side, along with HTML; what you've posted is PHP. PHP runs on the server and, typically, generates the HTML that's sent to the browser. If you want JavaScript help, then you need to post the relevant HTML as seen by the client's browser. For advice please take a read of the ["MCVE" guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/), and also "[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"

Comment: @user1974470 The solution you posted does appear to be working. If you notice on the left of the jsfiddle site, it shows that it is using the jQuery library. All you will need to do is include the jQuery library according to their documentation, then include the jsFiddle code replacing the selector (`#listF`) with `name="primary_cat"`.